# django+gunicorn+nginx, django admin return 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am working on django+gunicorn+nginx.
In the django admin, i am trying to delete an item 'user', which links to quite a lot of data in database, and it returns ' 504 Gateway Time-out' after 60 seconds.
Then I tried on changing the config of nginx and the one of gunicorn as below

in gunicorn:

```
timeout = 10000
```

and in nginx

```
    proxy_connect_timeout 50000;
    proxy_read_timeout 50000;
    proxy_send_timeout 50000;
```

But no matter what i have changed, the server always timeout after 60 seconds!

What can i do? I am total clueless...

And also the server is down too, i can't even ssh into it.
looks not a nginx/gunicorn config problem?

ngix.conf

```
##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

sites-enabled/app.conf

```
    location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
}

location @app {
    proxy_connect_timeout 50000;
    proxy_read_timeout 50000;
    proxy_send_timeout 50000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://xxx;
}
```

Comment: Did you restart nginx and gunicorn after making chanes?

Comment: Yes, I have and still 60s time out..

Comment: Are you sure that you're using your config file? Maybe try to execute your django app with gunicorn manually, setting the `--timeout` flag and check if it helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that it's using the config file, I updated the files to different value of TIMEOUT, and I then checked in ps -aux, the gunicorn has the --timeout xxx running parameters.

Comment: Does django admin itself has a timeout mechanism? When the query takes too long and it will return timeout...?

Comment: Can you hit gunicorn directly on its port number (bypass Nginx) and then try the operation?

Comment: @Will Keeling, I don't know how to bypass nginx...

Comment: For example if your site was accessible on `http://mysite/admin` and gunicorn listened on port 8000, then is it possible for you to hit `http://mysite:8000/admin` ?

Comment: Thank you! I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Can you also post your `nginx.conf`?

Comment: ok, please see my post for the *.conf above

Answer (score 1):

Set the timeout ngnix setings into the http{ ... } block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    #All block content...

    #Now the timeout settings:

    proxy_connect_timeout 50000;
    proxy_read_timeout 50000;
    proxy_send_timeout 50000;
}
```

Restart nginx

Comment: It's shown in the docs of the proxy module that the proxy timeout settings can be in both http, server and location contexts: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout